# How to query image information in a Libreoffice macro?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I've been looking for some way to obtain information about an image that I read from a file. Image size, etc. After lots of googleing, it seems you can do this using the com.sun.star.graphic.GraphicDescriptor service. The details of using this service are still not so clear though. I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light on this, prefarably with a (more or less) complete example, thanks.